# Не работают media запросы для article

Tags: css, scss

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
        .menu {
            width: 100%;
        }

        article  {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }
    }
```

Не работает медия запрос для article. Изначальные стили:

```
article {
    position: relative;

    &.big {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
    }

    &.medium {
        width: 50%;
        height: 370px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        float: left;
    }

    &.small {
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        height: 450px;
    }
```

}

Comment: Специфичность селекторов. `article.big`, имеет приоритет над просто `article` http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie

Comment: Огтомное спасибо!